# Share Photo on Facebook Group Wall

Tags: android, facebook, photo, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-wall

i'm trying to post a photo on facebook wall group, with the Android SDK for Facebook downloaded from Facebook Developer Site.
i tried this 2 command:

```
ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
.setContentTitle(title)
.setContentDescription(description)
.setContentUrl(uri).build();
```

and

```
SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder().setBitmap(image).build();
SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
.addPhoto(photo).build();
shareDialog.show(content);
```

With the first command I can share content where i want (Friend's wall, group's wall, my wall.) With the second one I can share content only on my wall.
There is a method to share photo in group's wall?
Thank you.

Comment: The dialog should present a dropdown for user to choose where to post the content.